# Add export button to Datables Editor

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

When using Datatables Editor plugin, I am trying to add the Export (excel, csv, etc) button besides the "New", "Edit" and "Delete" buttons.
My original code:

```
    new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, [
        { extend: "create", editor: editor },
        { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
        { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
    ]);
    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo( $('.col-md-6:eq(0)', table.table().container() ) );
} );
```

I then have tried to add the "export" buttons like this:

```
[
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor },
            {
                extend: "collection",
                text: 'Export',
                buttons: [
                    "copy",
                    "excel",
                    "csv",
                    "pdf",
                    "print"
                ]
            }
        ]
```

But it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button definitions should look like this:

```
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                   
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                   
                },
               {
                    extend: 'print',
                   
                },
                 {
                     extend: 'copy',
                   
                }
```

They are separate buttons, not a single button. You can add them in any order you want, so if you want them after the "Add, Edit, Delete" buttons, just add these definitions after those buttons.